# Jquery match link text to variable and add class

Tags: jquery, contains, addclass

Can anyone see where my brain fart is on this? the first part works great (set active nav ion main category pages) - but in the second part (set active nav/s on article pages) the items seem to match up without problem but the class doesn't get added. on these pages i need the main nav items to be set to active if they match up with the category links used in the article.

```
      /* Set active nav on main category pages */
      var currentPath = window.location.pathname,
          currentFilter = window.location.search,
          currentUrl = currentPath + currentFilter;
      //alert("currentUrl: " + currentUrl);
      $('#main-navigation li a[href="'+currentUrl+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active-link');


      /* Set active nav/s on library article pages (match ALL categories) */
      $('.view-item article .categories a').each(function(){
        var currentCategory = $(this).text();
        //alert("currentCategory: " + currentCategory);
        $('#main-navigation li a:contains("'+currentCategory+'")').parent('li').addClass('active-link'); 
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i FINALLY got this to WORK!!!

this works when i use the main navigation **class name instead of the id**, like this:

```
$(".main-nav li a:contains('"+currentCategory+"')").parent("li").addClass("active-link");
```

instead of this:

```
$("#main-navigation li a:contains('"+currentCategory+"')").parent("li").addClass("active-link");
```

Comment: ok - it seems like the reason for this was because the CMS template I'm using for the base of this site has two elements in the html named #main-navigation .... only one actually gets used based on the options selected when using the template - but since there are actually 2 #main-navigation elements in the html that get found when you run a script on that id, it won't work - so you need to use the class name instead.